# What is a good rune and Masteries Set to Maximize Malzahar as an AP Mid?

Tags: league-of-legends

What Runes and Mysteries should I use to maximize my AP Mid capabilities as Malzahar?  I would like to maximize his survivability, and his combo burst damage.

Comment: What are you maximizing? Damage, Sustainability, Movement...? Maximizing Malzahar is a little broad.

Answer (score 2):

- Mark:  Magic Penetration
- Seal: Mana Regen / Health / Armor
- Glyph: Magic Resist / Ability Power
- Quint: Move Speed or any of the above

This is a standard AP rune setup.  It provides more damage from abilities, some resistance vs your enemies abilities, and mana regeneration to stay in lane longer.

Note that this is a "typical" AP setup, and is much less effective against non-AP mids like Talon.

Answer (score 2):

1. In the mid, you are (usually) against another AP Carry, so have MR
   is a good thing.
2. As Malzahar you deal substantial damage in combo, so Magic
   Penetration is good to reduce the mitigation of your opponent
   (Dealing more damage in all the skills and make sure of the kill)

---

Taking this in consideration we have:

- **Mark (Red)** - Magic Penetration
- **Seal (Yellow)** - Your choice. My advise:
- Armor (Hold minions while doing harass)
- Magic Resistance (If you have trouble against AP carry too often)
- Ability power flat (For an early harass)
- Glyph (Blue) - Magic Resistance
- **Quint** -

  - Magic Penetration (If you are not confidente with the one you
    have).
  - Health (More durability in the lane).
  - Ability power flat (For an early harass)

Answer (score 0):

9x MP reds, 9X Clarity seals, 9x MR blues, 3x AP quints :P thats the way i use it good luck

MP-Gives you a load more damage for early game countering the opponents magic resist.

Clarity-Mana regen is good on many mages as it will make your spells more spamable and sometimes can even save your life because of it.

MR-Magic resist will give you defense against the opponent as he will probably be a mage too if hes a talon tho it wont work very well...

AP quints-Pretty self explainable use it on every mage as they will give you massive dmg for early game..

Comment: Could you explain the reasoning behind these choices?